# The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nodemailer

```
const registerDB = require('../Model/otp.module');
const quoteDB = require('../Model/quote.model')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const todaysQuote = require('./retrieveQuotes')

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:"smtp-mail.outlook.com",  
    port:587,
    secure:false,
    auth:{
        user:"SENDER EMAIL",
        pass:"PASSWORD"
    }
})

async function Send(email){

    const quote = await todaysQuote.RetriveQuote()

    let mailOptions={
        from:'SENDER',
        to:email,
        subject:"Quote for the day",
        text:quote
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error,info){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
     
        
        }
        else{
            console.log(info)
      
        }
    })


}

async function sendQuotes(){
    const quote = await registerDB.find({verified:true},{"_id":0,"__v":0})
    quote.map((email)=>{
        Send(email.email)

    })


}
module.exports={
sendQuotes
}
```

This is my code which extracts the which I write to extract the verified email and sends quote to each verified email. And I called `Send()` function to send email for each verified email. But on calling `Send()` function following error occurred `TypeError [ESTREAM]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Array`. I couldn't figure out where I went wrong.Can you please help me out on this issue. I am new to node.js and I am doing my first project.

Comment: what does `todaysQuote.RetriveQuote()` return (at a guess, it returns a Promise that resolves to an Array)